# Changing the behavior of this inside object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got two objects i.e.

```
var Parent = { };

var Child = {
    born : function () {
        Parent.beHappy = this.study;
    },

    study : function () {
        console.log("Studying!");
        console.log("Now I'm going to play");
        this.play();
    },

    play : function () {
        console.log("Playing!");
    }
}
```

Now, what I am doing is

```
Child.born();
Parent.beHappy();
```

As you can see `Parent.beHappy()` calls the `study` method of child. Now the problem I am having is, in the `study` method I cannot call `this.play()`. And the reason, why is it so is because `study()` is being called on `Parent` and so `this` here refers to `Parent` instead of `Child`. Is there any way that I can make `this` in the `study` method always refer to `Child` and not the `Parent`? I know that I can do `Child.play()` in the `study` method to make it work, but I would like to be consistent throughout my code and would prefer `this`. Also, I could do `$.proxy(Parent.beHappy, Child)()`, but I don't want to change this `Parent.beHappy()` function call, because it will be used by the end user. I have tried everything and now I am out of ideas. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: it appears as though you don't want to change the code at all!

Comment: @Amin Jafari There are hundred ways to do a thing, I had only specified the two that I didn't want. Still there were 98 others to chose from ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set context using `.bind()` js method:

```
Parent.beHappy = this.study.bind(this);
```

Or to support even older browsers, use jQuery $.proxy():

```
Parent.beHappy = $.proxy(this.study, this);
```

```js
var Parent = { };

var Child = {
    born : function () {
        Parent.beHappy = $.proxy(this.study, this);
    },

    study : function () {
        snippet.log("Studying!");
        console.log("Studying!");
        console.log("Now I'm going to play");
        snippet.log("Now I'm going to play");
        this.play();
    },

    play : function () {
        console.log("Playing!");
        snippet.log("Playing!");
    }
}

Child.born();
Parent.beHappy();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: `snippet.log();` ! When did this happen..! One more [feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214) to strike down..

Comment: @TJ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239706/add-a-console-to-stack-snippets/242144#242144  Thx to T.J. Crowder